# How to incorporate Material Design in App when using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Am learning android app development and using android studio. I want to get material design feel and look. Am following android developer website and came across `android:Theme.Material` theme but it says its not supported in API older than API level 21! https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

I googled but still have lots of confusion if there is proper support library for material design if not how can we achieve it for older version? It will be really helpful if someone can point me to proper link/guides/tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AppCompat v21 (or later)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    ...
}
```

and with this `values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```

So basically you can use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and theme the above style.

For more details see: [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) (which is also kris larson mentioned in his answer)

Answer (score 2):

the support libraries for material design

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

the material design theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the libraries. So if am using Theme.AppCompat as parent theme am already using material theme?

Comment: Yes, you can define `<item name="colorPrimary">` , `<item name="colorAccent">` inside it.  But you need to add some libraries for using material design components

Comment: The `Activities` in your application should extend `AppCompatActivity`, and you should define a toolbar in the layout file.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Am using toolbar and also other material widgets using libraries. If you can point out some links/tutorials for further it will be helpful. Otherwise am good to go till now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article on Android Developer's Blog about the Material Design support library:

[Android Design Support Library | Android Developer's Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Comment: Thanks! Nice tutorial.